Calculating the Net Amount on Sales Order Line using a custom formula
I have to calculate the Net Amount on Sales Order Line by adding the number of months for which the item will be sold on that price. For this purpose, I have created extension of the form SalesTable and used the event handler OnValidating for the Data Field 'Line Amount'.
Following is the code I have written:
[Extensionof(formStr(SalesTable))]
final class PRMSC_SalesLine_Extension
{

     //<summary>

     //</summary>
     //<param name="sender"></param>
     //<param name="e"></param>
    [FormControlEventHandler(formControlStr(SalesTable, SalesLine_LineAmount), FormControlEventType::Validating)]
    public static void SalesLine_LineAmount_OnValidating(FormControl sender, FormControlEventArgs e)
    {
        SalesLine  _salesLine;
        _salesLine.LineAmount = (_salesLine.SalesPrice)*(_salesLine.SalesQty)*(_salesLine.PRMSC_NoOfMonths);
        FormControlCancelableSuperEventArgs cancelableSuperEventArgs = e as FormControlCancelableSuperEventArgs;
        cancelableSuperEventArgs.CancelSuperCall();
    }
}

The build and DB sync went fine without errors but still the calculation of line amount does not include the number of months field

And when you put a breakpoint inside that code and debug, does it break in the debugger?

On debugging, I inserted the breakpoint at the line of code where I am providing the new formula for Line Amount and It was not hit by the compiler. I am guessing since the event handler is on the OnValidating of the field , it is not getting hit

Even on changing the formeventcontrol to OnModified, it is getting hit but the formula does not include Number of months in the calculation

You have no data in the _salesLine, init the buffer:
 FormRun        formRun         = sender.formRun() as FormRun;
 FormDataSource salesLine_ds    = formRun.dataSource(formDataSourceStr(SalesTable, SalesLine)) as FormDataSource;
 SalesLine      _salesLine      = salesLine_ds.cursor();


I have used OnModified for the custom field. The lineAmount(NetAmount) is being calculated right but if I save and any mandatory field is not filled, the line amount value reverts back to the system formula and I have to again write the value of custom field to get the custom calculated value of LineAmount. I have tried datasource.reread() and datasource.refresh() as well but it stays the same

@SabaIqbal - that insert() behaviour sounds really odd. What if you extend in the form data source both insert() and update(), in both after the super() call, you call a new method in where you make the calculation and doUpdate()?

I have tried extending the update method. The problem with extending update is whenever 'Save' button will be clicked, Line Amount will be calculated again despite no change in the qty or unit price fields and the line amount will go up.

@SabaIqbal - then empty the value before the calculation? Though I cannot understand why it would increase with a simple "+".
